# Storing and loading data from react-native calendar to a JSON file

Tags: json, react-native

I'm currently thinking of a concept for a react-native app where people add events over a period of time like a diary/log. These events need to be exported and for security and privacy reasons I don't want to use a database. I've read you can use JSON files as a storage method, too.

How can I store data from the app to a JSON file and load the data from the JSON file back in the app? Don't need any code, helpful articles or webpages are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have all the app data into a json, its rather simple.

1. Decide where to store the appdata.json, lets call it APP_DATA_PATH
2. Find a library to read/write files (I've only used [expo-file-system](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/))
3. On app boot, check if APP_DATA_PATH exists, if it does read the file and load into app, if not assume its a new user
4. Whenever app data changes, write the changes to APP_DATA_PATH